# Group by, distinct, count in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

What would be the equivalent statement for querying model in Django

```
select distinct final_category, count(responders) 
from johnson_jnjusage 
where no_of_people_house = "4" and 
      child_age_group="0 to 12 months" and 
      city = "HYDERABAD" and 
      nursing_cnt = "2ND TIME MOTHER" and 
      bucket="BRAND PENETRATION" 
group by final_category;
```

Thanks

Comment: Detail information regarding grouping, distinct and aggregation is available in Django Documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#making-queries and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [Django docs for aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/aggregation/#values), it might look something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Usage.objects.filter(no_of_people_house='4', city='HYDERABAD', nursing_cnt='2ND TIME MOTHER', bucket='BRAND PENETRATION').values('final_category').annotate(responders=Count('responders'))
```

The order of the filter, values and annotate clauses is important as it defines how the aggregation behaves.